# send message to master page from non content page - asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, master-pages

Is it possible to send message to master page from non content page in asp.net.

Here is the scenario:

1- User click the button on content page A, which then open a new window (new browser page) X

2- User upload few documents in new window X

3- While doucments are being uploaded on page X, user navigates through different pages. He might be on page A or page B when uploading is done on page X.

4- Message needs to be sent to main website saying 'documents are uploaded'

Question 1: Is this possible what i am trying to achieve.

Question 2: If yes then what are the different ways to send the message back to main website?

Comment: If the upload window is opened via javascript, then you can use "window.opener" to refer to the window which opened the iframe.  You can call functions which are present in the main window via window.opener.  With that in mind, you could define a function on the master page which displays a message when called.  The upload window could call that function via the window.opener property once uploads are finished.

Comment: After upload is finished, the user might not be on the same window which opened that new window.

Comment: Then you need to do this server side.  Have the upload window update some data on the server associated with that given user (could be stored in a database, session variable etc.) and have the master page regularly poll for updates for the user and display a message accordingly.

Comment: any other possibility?